# Swiftで、xibで作成したTableViewCellに、xibで作成したViewを追加

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

#### はじめに

SwiftでiOSのアプリを開発しています。初心者です。
こういった質問サイトへの投稿経験も浅いため、マナーや通例に反した質問をしてしまっているかもしれません。
もしかすると、お門違いな点もあるかと思いますが、ご容赦願います。

---

#### 本題

**所定のボタンを押すことで、xibで作成したTableViewCell（カスタムクラス : CustomTableViewCell.swift）の中に、xibで作成したView（カスタムクラス : CustomView.swift）を追加（addSubview）しようとしています。**
しかし、以下問題が生じています。解決方法を教えてください。

**CustomTableViewCell.swift**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var viewInCell: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    } 
}
```

**CustomView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    class func instance() -> CustomView {
        return UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView
    }

}
```

（**詳細1**）
CustomTableViewCellの中にViewを配置して、CustomTableViewCell.swiftにアウトレット接続しています。そして、 TableViewが配置されているViewController（MyViewController.swift）に、ボタンをアクション接続し、そのメソッドの中に、「"特定のセル"の（アウトレット接続した）Viewに、CustomViewをaddSubViewする」記述を書いています。

（**詳細2**）
上記の特定のセルはTableViewの「visibleCells」プロパティで取得しています。

**MyViewController.swift**

```
 @IBAction func testBtn(sender: UIButton) {
        for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [CustomTableViewCell]{
            let myView = CustomView.instance()
            cell.viewInCell.frame = myView.frame
            cell.viewInCell.addSubview(myView)
        }
    }
```

---

#### 発生している問題

**1.addSubviewしたCustomViewが、CutomTableViewCellで定義したViewをはみ出て表示される。**
    ちなみに、CustomTableViewCell内の「awakeFromNib()」で、以下の様にaddSubviewした場合は、

```
let myView = CustomView.instance()
cell.viewInCell.frame = myView.frame
cell.viewInCell.addSubview(myView)
```

Viewをはみ出ることなく表示されます。

**2.スクロールすると、addSubviewしたCustomViewが「visibleCells」で取得したセル以外のセルに反映される。また、スクロールして戻ってくると、そのCustomViewが消えていたりする。**
    こちらのサイト（http://ios-practice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/tableview/）に、それらしき記述はあるのですが、Objective-cの知識がないことと、私の読解力のなさから自分のコードに適用するに至っておりません。また、これが本質的な解決方法であるのかも判断できていません。

---

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

Xcode version7.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.addSubviewしたCustomViewが、CutomTableViewCellで定義したViewをはみ出て表示される。

`cell.viewInCell`のプロパティ`clipsToBounds`を`true`にしてください。これは、Interface BuilderのAttributes Inspectorでも変更できます。
`UIView`のデフォルトでは、サブビューは、スーパービューのフレームをはみ出して、配置することができるようになっています。スーパービューからはみ出した部分を表示しないようにするには、このプロパティを変更します。

```
cell.viewInCell.clipsToBounds = true
```

> 2.スクロールすると、addSubviewしたCustomViewが「visibleCells」で取得したセル以外のセルに反映される。また、スクロールして戻ってくると、そのCustomViewが消えていたりする。

`UITableView`の、セルを再利用するメカニズムの概要を理解しないと、問題の所在が把握できないと思います。テーブルの表示範囲に、たとえば10行が並んでいるとすると、セルの総数はせいぜいプラス2〜3個、12〜13個しかありません。テーブルの全行数だけセルが作られるのではなく、スクロールして非表示になったセルは、すぐにスクロールして表示される行に再利用されることを、理解する必要があります。
『addSubviewしたCustomViewが「visibleCells」で取得したセル以外のセルに反映される。』のではなく、CustomViewをaddSubviewしたセルが、そのままテーブルの別の行に再利用されるのです。
『スクロールして戻ってくると、そのCustomViewが消えていたりする』のではなく、CustomViewをaddSubviewしていないセルが、スクロールして再表示になった行に再利用されているのです。

なので、

```
let myView = CustomView.instance()
cell.viewInCell.frame = myView.frame
cell.viewInCell.addSubview(myView)
```

このコードは、`CustomTableViewCell`の`awakeFromNib()`あたり（曖昧な表現で申し訳ありませんが）に実装するのが妥当と思われます。

Comment: 丁寧で、とても分かりやすく、腹落ちいたしました。ありがとうございます。

1.に関して、便利なプロパティを知ることができました。ただ、今回は、そちらを適応しても、サブビューがはみ出てしまいました。
2.セルの再利用のお話は、完全に晴天の霹靂でした。根本的に解釈が間違っていました。そして、となると、私が今回実現したいことは、今の設計では色々不具合がでることを確信いたしました。（上記、レイアウトの崩れもそれが原因である可能性が高いです。）

もう一度、改めて、設計し直したいと思います。ありがとうございます。